# How can I use a single SQL string to create a data-set from multiple tables in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, oledbdataadapter, oledbdatareader

I'm new to C#, and I'm kinda clueless about how to use a single sql-string to retrieve data from multiple tables (3 of them, actually).

basically there are 2 master-files:

- Task_Information, Emp_Information

And 1 transaction-file:

- Assignments: this one gets updated by the primary keys of the 2 master-files and a few other fields.

And that's alright. But now i need to run a command that will retrieve data from ALL 3 tables based on a search-parameter entered by the user, and display selected fields in all of them. in ms access, all i had to do was make a query - here's the generated sql:

```
SELECT Assignments.Task_No, Assignments.Assignment_No, Assignments.Assignment_Date,
       Task_Information.Client_Name, Emp_Information.F_Name, Emp_Information.L_Name
  FROM Emp_Information 
       INNER JOIN (Task_Information 
                   INNER JOIN Assignments ON Task_Information.Task_No = Assignments.Task_No) 
             ON Emp_Information.Emp_ID = Assignments.Assignee
  WHERE (((Assignments.Assignment_Date)="this is just some date the user has to enter..."))
```

In short, I need to find out how to use the same sql-string in a C# program where the user types the search parameter and clicks a button. btw, it's got to be done with an oledbdatareader/adapter;

Comment: Are you using SQL server now?  or still MS Access?

Comment: I'm using MS Access. I connected it to my C# application via an oledb connection, and i wanted to run a query that would retrieve fields from 3 related tables. I used the oledbdatareader and had to make a few adjustments. It works fine now. Except I still can't figure out how to display all matching records - ryt now i can only retrieve one row and display them on textboxes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
 SELECT Assignments.Task_No, Assignments.Assignment_No, Assignments.Assignment_Date,
 Task_Information.Client_Name, Emp_Information.F_Name, Emp_Information.L_Name
  FROM Emp_Information 
  INNER JOIN Task_Information 
  ON Task_Information.Task_No = Assignments.Task_No 
  INNER JOIN Assignments 
  ON Emp_Information.Emp_ID = Assignments.Assignee
  WHERE (((Assignments.Assignment_Date) like "%this is just some date the user has to enter...%"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different.. Could you please explain a bit more..? Thank you so much.

Comment: you make mistake on join query just compare my give sql query and your sql query you can find what difference between them. You are user on condition at wrong place.

Comment: if you still not getting any think tell me... @user1420202

Answer (score 0):

if you would work with an SQL Server you could use the [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx). With this you would replace your string `"this is..."` with a parameter placeholder `@date`, which could then be set like [shown on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

The main problem here would be the usage of the [`OleDbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.aspx) and if it supports this kind of query. But after reading the MSDN for [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will read more on oledbcommand.parameters. Thanks again!